# Java calendar format is not printing the desired output

Tags: java, datetime

MY CODE

```
    String strtime="15:30";
    Duration="60";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date date = formatter.parse(strtime);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(duration));

    String endTime = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

The above code adds the minutes and prints the correct o/p if my time is in 12 hour format. But when in 24 hour format it gives me the wrong o/p
For example if i give strtime=15:30 it give me o/p as 4:30 where as I need it as 16:30 
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use capital 'H' to get 24-hour format:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

See the Javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you're supposed to capitalize the letter for a different result:

`H  Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12`